# How to use HTML as input to Hakyll

Tags: haskell, hakyll

I use [Hakyll](http://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/) for my [blog](http://haroldcarr.com/).

I currently write my posts in
[emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)
[org-mode](http://orgmode.org/) and then have org-mode export to
[markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown).
Then Hakyll turns that markdown into HTML.

That works OK but I would like finer-grained control of the HTML that
gets posted.  What I would rather do is have org-mode export to HTML
and then have Hakyll use that HTML as input.

Note: my blog is working fine with markdown input, I just want to use
(org-mode generated) HTML as input instead.

Hakyll's [opening page](http://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/) says "WRITE YOUR
CONTENT IN WHATEVER FORMAT YOU PREFER" so HTML input does work (I
tried it somewhat successfully).

Hakyll's
[FAQ](http://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/tutorials/faq.html#pandoccompilerhakyllpandoc-eats-my-html)
says to use `getResourceBody` instead of `pandocCompiler` when inputting HTML.

What I haven't figured out yet is how to handle title, tags and teasers when using HTML as input.

A typical markdown post would be

```
---
title: Switching to Hakyll
tags: hakyll, haskell, pandoc, emacs, org-mode, markdown
---

I chose [Hakyll](http://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/) for blog software ...

<!-- MORE -->

I write posts in [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) ...
```

QUESTIONS:

1. where/how do I put/format title and tags in the HTML input?
2. what code do I use to process the title/tags?
3. where/how do I put/format the "teaser" marker in the HTML input?
4. what code do I use to process the teaser?

Examples would be great, or at least pointers to relevant doc.

**UPDATE**

As suggested by @duplode, when I replace `pandocCompiler` with `getResourceBody` it handles the content and the teaser correctly.   But the tags are not seen.   They just end up in the HTML output.

The HTML input is like:

```
.
.
.
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<h1 class="title">2013-06-30-test-post</h1>
---
title: My first org-mode post
tags: emacs, org-mode
---

<p>
Does it work?
</p>

<!-- MORE -->

<p>
This is the rest.
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work exactly in the same way. The metadata header (i.e. the block between the `---`) is specific to Hakyll, and not tied to markdown syntax. The same goes for the other functionality. When you replace `pandocCompiler` with `getResourceBody`, the only effect is to skip the pandoc markup conversion step, and so nothing else in the processing needs to change.

Comment: Doing that replacement worked for the content and the teaser. But not for the metadata header.

Comment: Your update to the question has clarified the issue. The metadata header should be at the very top of the file, above `<head>` and everything else. Hakyll will strip it from the final HTML output, so you don't have to worry about malformed HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use your HTML as a template, you should probably take a look at [applyAsTemplate](http://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/hakyll4/reference/Hakyll-Web-Template.html)

You can also take a look at my [blog's source code](https://github.com/hgad/site/blob/master/bin/site.hs) for examples.

Comment: It looks like your posts are in markdown.   Using getResourceBody (instead of pandocCompiler) worked for the post and the teaser.  But I need to understand how to get the metadata (i.e., title and tags) in the HTML input handled properly.

Comment: My static pages (like about.html, archive.html, etc.) are not in Markdown. They're HTML. You basically need to use applyAsTemplate to instruct Hakyll to treat your resource as both, a resource and a template.

Comment: thanks - I do understand that.   But your static pages do not have tags as posts do.   I'm trying to figure out how to get the tags processed with POSTS in HTML.